# SQL to return fixed data in both SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need a common select statement that returns a fixed value / row without the need of tables, which has to work with both Oracle & Sql Server.

eg for Oracle I know I can use:

```
select 'O' AS INDICATOR from DUAL;
```

But this won't work on Sql Server.

Can this be done with the same SQL on both Oracle & SQL Server?

Comment: Are you writing a data layer that will work on both kinds of databases?

Comment: Haven't used oracle for a while but what about `select * from (select 'O' as Indicator) T`

Comment: @Alex - Orable's select requires the existence of a `from` clause.

Comment: @Raj More No, I'm using an existing application (JasperServer) and I need to create what they call a 'Derived Table' which returns only this. Unfortunately the SQL is stored in the repository and is fixed, and so cannot be abstracted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you'll need different queries, unless you can find a table that exists both on the SQL Server and on the Oracle Server.

Oracle uses the `DUAL` table for dummy queries, while the syntax to just select a constant on SQL server is a bit simpler:

```
select 'O' as Indicator
```

will return a one-row recordset.

P.S. If you intend to write just standard SQL and have it work on both SQL Server and Oracle, note that there are lots and lots of differences, even if you do not use database-side code (stored procedures and functions).

Off the top of my head, some things that are different:

- Case statement syntax
- NVL vs IsNull
- Null sorting behaviour
- Data conversion functions
- String manipulation functions
- etc, etc.

Comment: The tables in the databases are the same, so yes I can use this suggestion eg :

select distinct 'O' as INDICATOR from SOME_COMMON_TABLE;

Comment: @Neil, the downside selecting from SOME_COMMON_TABLE is you probably being doing IO against that table. If you were able to use two different queries for SQL Server and Oracle of the proper form for each, you'd avoid the IO. (Given a late enough version of Oracle, the supports "fast dual")

Answer (score 2):

You can't select data in Oracle without from statement. So you **need** to have a table in Oracle (common practice is to use standard table - Dual). The best solution if you **really** need to run same query on both database servers is to create Dual table with only one row in MS SQL. But really it's better to use different queries for different servers (maybe via some abstraction layer).

Comment: Yes this would work but I'm trying to get away from creating pseudo tables

Answer (score 2):

Use a [common table expression (CTE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) e.g.

```
WITH D (INDICATOR)
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('O')
             ) T (c1)
     )
SELECT INDICATOR 
  FROM D;
```

Or more simply in line:

```
SELECT *
 FROM (
       VALUES ('O')
      ) D (INDICATOR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the *DUAL* table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE DUAL (DUMMY NVARCHAR(1) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO DUAL VALUES ('X');
```

and then use the same query as in Oracle:

```
select 'O' AS INDICATOR from DUAL;
```

Comment: Same as above.Yes this would work but I'm trying to get away from creating pseudo tables